# Name of the intermediate in between phosphono and phosphonato group

Tags: acid-base, stereochemistry, amino-acids

$\ce{R-PO3^2-}$ is called a phoshonato group (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=30931)

$\ce{R-PO3H2}$ is called a phosphono group (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=48108)

So, what is: $\ce{R-PO3H-}$ called ? I can't find it, it seems to be largely ignored.
Auxiliary question, is one of the two possible enantiomers of this form dominant ? Is there anyway to know this ? Or is it by definition distributed in a 50%/50% manner ?

Comment: Edited back to the original format (what was that edit anyway ?)

Comment: — Monophosphonic acid